# date comparison in sql server

Tags: sql-server, date-comparison, date-math

I am trying to display records which have their date (I have a column Date in table) 30 days back from today's date. And once it gets displayed I need to make a new record by adding details with Date= today's date.. 
I tried this:

```
select * from 
paymenthist 
where 
Date = CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()), 101))
```

But all records are getting displayed..

Comment: You have a couple of answers below that you'll want to consider serious performance implications of casting/converting every record in the table.

Comment: Any reason for converting to `VARCHAR` and then back to `DATE`?

Comment: Are you trying to get a specific date 30 days ago or a range of days back from now to 30 days ago? Either way, if the "Date" field is of type datetime (or datetime2) and not of type date, then you'll need to search on a range of time, beginning with the beginning of the first day, up to and not including the beginning of the day following the last day. I.e., "where Date > x AND Date <= y".

Comment: I am trying to get all the records only of a specific date 30 days back.. Using above gives error: conversion from char to datetime  resulted in out of range value!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I admit the way I suggested may be inefficient, but if one is a datetime and the other is a date then I believe this will be more efficient than the >= <= approach because SQL is often not great at utilising indexes for queries like this, and under the covers a datetime is actually a floating point, so for pure efficiency, try this:

```
CREATE TABLE ##PaymentHistory
(
ID INT IDENTITY,
[Date] DATETIME,
Col1 INT,
Col2 INT
)

INSERT INTO ##PaymentHistory([Date],Col1,Col2)
VALUES(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() -29 AS FLOAT) ) ,1,1)
, (FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() -30 AS FLOAT) ) ,2,2)
, (FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() -31 AS FLOAT) ) ,3,3)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT ##PaymentHistory ON

INSERT INTO ##PaymentHistory(ID, [Date], Col1, Col2)
SELECT ID, GETDATE(), Col1, Col2 
FROM ##PaymentHistory 
WHERE CAST(Date AS FLOAT) = FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() -30 AS FLOAT) ) 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT ##PaymentHistory OFF
```

Comment: Using this my previous records are getting changed...otherwise i.e. for expected records it is working

Comment: When you say your previous records are being changed, do you mean it is also returning results for day-31, day-32 etc?

Comment: ya..Its Id gets changed. I just need to add new records with Id remaining same but date=+30 from previous record for the same Id and add a few more details.. ID and date is a composite primary key..

Comment: Is the ID and Identity column? If so you will need to SET IDENTITY INSERT PaymentHistory ON and specify each column in the insert statement individually

Comment: can you please elaborate on SET IDENTITY INSERT or post a link about it.. I am not well aware about it.. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have updated this answer to incude a full working sample using a Temp Table. It assumes that the ID column is an Identity column.

Answer (score -1):

It depends somewhat on the datatype of the date column, but try this.

```
select * from paymenthist where cast(Date as date) =  cast(DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) as date)
```

Comment: Same comment as above - You don't want to perform converts in this way on fields in your where clause.